# Laravel save checkbox value in database

Tags: laravel, forms, checkbox

i would like to save the value (checked or unchecked) in my database, this is so when i refresh it shows the state it was left in when i press "save".

I was looking into this on this site and other, but just couldnt find the right thing.
So i was looking for alternatives like LocalStorage, but this wasnt really what i was looking for.

Here's the code I'm trying to make work

```
<form action="{{action('InstagramAccountController@config', $id)}}" method="post">
                {{csrf_field()}}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="followSwitch">Follow</label>
                    <div>
                    <label class="switch">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="follow" value="1" checked>
                        <span class="slider round"></span>
                    </label>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="likeSwitch">Like</label>
                    <div>
                    <label class="switch">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="like" value="1" checked>
                        <span class="slider round"></span>
                    </label>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="commentSwitch">Comment</label>
                    <div>
                    <label class="switch">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="comment" value="1" checked>
                        <span class="slider round"></span>
                    </label>
                    </div>
                </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a href="/instagram" class="btn btn-secondary">Close</a>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Part of the controller:

```
public function Config($id){
        $instagramAccount = InstagramAccount::find($id);
        return view('instagramAccountConfig', compact('instagramAccount', 'id'));
    }
```

Something i found regarding this (maybe unrelated?):

```
/* ROUTE FORCONFIG 
Route::post('/', function(){
    $box = Input::has('follow') ? true : false;
    $box = Input::has('like') ? true : false;
    $box = Input::has('comment') ? true : false;

    Config::create([
        'follow'=> $box,
        'like'=> $box,
        'comment'=> $box,
    ]);
    return 'created';
});
END*/
```

If anybody has any idea for this and my controller, (maybe more than just those 2) please leave a solution and/or a link to where I can find how to solve this.

Thanks.

Comment: Also please do tell if just everything is wrong, and perhaps leave a link to some place where it is right. Starting over doesnt matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Change the code like this. Get the input from $request.

```
    Route::post('/', function(Request $request){
      $follow = $request('follow') ? true : false;
      $like = $request('like') ? true : false;
      $comment = $request('comment') ? true : false;

      Config::create([
        'follow'=> $follow,
        'like'=> $like,
        'comment'=> $comment,
    ]);
    return 'created';
});
```

Comment: When i tried this it said ``` The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD. ``` , I then tried to use "get" instead of post in the form and in the route, but still the same error. Any idea?

Comment: May be changing your action to {{url('/')}} in the form will solved the problem.

Comment: I tried, still the same error. Thanks though, I will come back tomorrow to see if there are more answers.

Comment: And you can also check by giving another route url. In action it will be like {{ url('/save-config')}}. And then add Route::post('/save-config'). I think it will solve your problem.